# Return a filtered array based on user input javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, scope

I have an user input.

Based on that input I need to filter an array of options.

I have been able to submit the data, I am now inside my `handleSubmitData` function where I am writing the `if` conditions which should then return a filtered array of results to the screen however this is not happening. It must be to do with scope however I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong. Here is the code. Any guidance would be helpful

```
const Container = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([
    "studentCard",
    "anywhereCard",
    "liquidCard",
  ]);
  

  const handleSubmitData = (userInput) => {
    const { employmentStatus } = userInput.state;
    const { earnings } = userInput.state;

    if (employmentStatus === "student" && earnings < 16000) {
      return cards.filter((card) => card !== "liquidCard");
    }
    if (employmentStatus === "student" && earnings >= 16000) {
      return cards;
    }
    return cards;
  };

  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <UserInputForm submitData={handleSubmitData} />
        {cards} 
    </div>
  );
};

export default Container;
```

I have put `cards` within my `render return` part of the component  but nothing happens there are no filtered cards..

Comment: `cards` is a state object so you need to update it using `setCards` if you want to see the results. Be careful of mutation here, and you'll probably want a second state array to hold the filtered results so that you can return to the unfiltered state.

Comment: Thank you v much for your explanation @pilchard that makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set filtered cards to `cards` state on `handleSubimitData`.

```js
const Container = () => {
  const allCards = ['studentCard', 'anywhereCard', 'liquidCard'];
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmitData = userInput => {
    const { employmentStatus } = userInput.state;
    const { earnings } = userInput.state;

    let filtered = [...allCards];

    if (employmentStatus === 'student' && earnings < 16000) {
      filtered = allCards.filter(card => card !== 'liquidCard');
    }

    setCards(filtered);
  };

  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <UserInputForm submitData={handleSubmitData} />
      {cards}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Container;
```

Comment: Thanks @baymax i decided to go with your answer as it was a lot cleaner as i have 4 if statements to include. Makes sense. Will remember for next time I need the filtered data to be separate from the data in the state

Answer (score 3):

If you return something, it's not gonna re-render it again, you have to update the state

for EX:

```
const filterdCards = cards.filter((card) => card !== "liquidCard");
setCards(filterdCards);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to render only the filtered cards, you could do this.

```
const Container = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([
    "studentCard",
    "anywhereCard",
    "liquidCard",
  ]);
 const [filteredCards,setFilteredCards = useState(["studentCard",
    "anywhereCard",
    "liquidCard",])
  

  const handleSubmitData = (userInput) => {
    const { employmentStatus } = userInput.state;
    const { earnings } = userInput.state;

    if (employmentStatus === "student" && earnings < 16000) {
      setFilteredCards(cards.filter((card) => card !== "liquidCard"))
    }
    else if (employmentStatus === "student" && earnings >= 16000) {
      setFilteredCards(cards)
    } else {
    setFilteredCards(cards)
   }
  };

  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <UserInputForm submitData={handleSubmitData} />
        {filteredCards} 
    </div>
  );
};

export default Container;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the state if you want to see changes in the UI, instead of doing those `return` statements. (use `setCards`)